# Apple Omniauth - HTTP Origin header (https://appleid.apple.com) didn't match request.base_url (https://myurl.com)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-7, apple-oauth2

i am trying to implement `omniauth-apple` in my rails app and get the following error after apple redirects to my page.

`HTTP Origin header (https://appleid.apple.com) didn't match request.base_url (https://myurl.com)`

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Hello, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know yet. but looks like the gem 'omniauth-apple' is not properly maintained. So I would recommend building it from scratch and/or use the gem 'apple_id' to expedite part of the development.